# error while running 'flutter packages get' command

Tags: firebase, flutter, package

This error happens while running the command 'flutter packages get'. I have added few dependencies for pubspec.yaml file to use firebase authentication:

```
name: flutter_auth
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

After execution of `flutter pub get` command I'm getting following error:

```
PS C:\Users\ajant\Downloads\myapp\myapp> flutter packages get        
Because cloud_firestore >=0.11.0 <0.13.3 depends on firebase_core ^0.4.0 and flutter_auth depends on firebase_core ^1.0.1, cloud_firestore 
>=0.11.0 <0.13.3 is forbidden.
So, because flutter_auth depends on cloud_firestore ^0.12.9+5, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in Welcome-Login-Signup-Page-Flutter-master...             
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_auth depends on cloud_firestore ^0.12.9+5, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: What happens if you change cloud_firestore-version to  "1.0.1"?

Answer (score 0):

Try change the dependencies to their current versions:

```
   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
   firebase_core: ^1.0.1
   firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
   cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
   firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
   google_sign_in: ^5.0.0
```

You can find the current version by google searching the dependencies one by one and find the current version in the installing tab. Here is one example:

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/install